# How do I remove events from Eventhub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I might be confused how EventHubs supposed to be used or need guidance on how to reliably process events posted into Eventhub. I export Azure ActivityLog to Eventhub and currently just using console application to read those messages. What I don't understand is what I'm supposed to do with events which I already read and processed. Say I want to write content of all messages into Storage account AppendLog. For this I need to delete messages which I already processed (like it would be done if it will be message queue), how do I do that with eventhub?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot delete them. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#partitions):

> Event Hubs retains data for a configured retention time that applies across all partitions in the event hub. Events expire on a time basis; you cannot explicitly delete them.

Back to your question:

> Say I want to write content of all messages into Storage account AppendLog. *For this I need to delete messages which I already processed*

I am not sure why you need this though. You can keep a pointer to the last read message so you are able to process only new messages. Why should you need to delete the older ones? You can read about offsets and ceckpointing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#event-consumers).

What technique are you using for reading the messages?

Comment: Say I would have a function which will need to react to those events but function was not running for some reason for sometime. When I start a function it will react only to new events, but how do I process backlog then?

Comment: Well, ideally the function should use checkpointing so that when the function resumes it work after being stopped it will continue with the last message + 1 after the last run. If you use an EventProcessorHost you get this for free: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host#checkpointing. So *When I start a function it will react only to new events* only applies if you do not apply checkpointing.

Comment: So if I use EventProcessorHost even though it's not always running, it will keep track of last processed event when instantiated through Function?

Comment: *when instantiated through Function* Are we talking about Azure Functions here? In that case don't worry at all since it already keeps track of last processed events, see last alinea of [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#trigger---scaling) in the scaling section.

Comment: What happens to that pointer if another solutions reads the same hub? Like for example I subscribe to it via Logic App. Is this pointer per Consumer Group Name or application?

Comment: Per partition per consumer group. Event hub allows just one concurrent reader per partition per consumer group so you are covered

Answer (score 0):

If you need a pattern of popping messages, you need the Queue or Topic from the Azure Service Bus.
When you ack that message, it is popped from the queue.